# Tabulating the results of %in%

Tags: r

I have a list of IDs such as:

```
ids1 <- c(0, 2, 3, 4, 8)
```

Then I have another list of IDs, such as

```
ids2 <- c(2, 4, 5, 7, 11)
```

I would like to produce a data.frame as follows:

```
ID   in      out
0    FALSE   TRUE
2    TRUE    FALSE
3    FALSE   TRUE
4    TRUE    FALSE
8    FALSE   TRUE
```

That is, for each element in `ids1` I would like a row in the output along with 2 columns that indicate whether or not the element in `ids1` exists in `ids2`.

I know I can do things like

```
ids1[ids1 %in% ids2]
```

and

```
ids1[!(ids1 %in% ids2)]
```

which gives me the TRUE values for each column, but I can't figure out how to make the data.frame from it.

Please note that a base R or tidyverse solution is OK, but not data.table please

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use, `data.frame` itself to construct.  The output of `%in%` is a logical vector.  When we subset with `[`, it returns the corresponding value where the TRUE values are present

```
data.frame(ID = ids1, `in` = ids1 %in% ids2, 
      out = !ids1 %in% ids2, check.names = FALSE)
```

-output

```
 ID    in   out
1  0 FALSE  TRUE
2  2  TRUE FALSE
3  3 FALSE  TRUE
4  4  TRUE FALSE
5  8 FALSE  TRUE
```

---

Or in `tibble`

```
library(tibble)
tibble(ID = ids1, `in` = ids1 %in% ids2, out = !`in`)
# A tibble: 5 x 3
     ID `in`  out  
  <dbl> <lgl> <lgl>
1     0 FALSE TRUE 
2     2 TRUE  FALSE
3     3 FALSE TRUE 
4     4 TRUE  FALSE
5     8 FALSE TRUE
```

Comment: You win again ;-). My only addition was along the lines of *"if both vectors are large, one might prefer to calculate `in` and then `dat$out <- !dat$\`in\``"*.

Comment: @r2evans yes, you are right.  I would have used `within`

Comment: or `transform`.

Comment: @r2evans but, `transform` may have an issue with accessing the previous column (not tested though)

Comment: Yeah, I was thinking `transform(data.frame(...), out = !\`in\`)` or similar. Good point though.